# LaTeX beamer: Code listings in notes

Tags: beamer, listings

How can I add a code listing to a `beamer` note slide?

I tried the following which doesn't work:

```
\note{{\tiny{This is a note
      \begin{lstlisting}
foo bar
      \end{lstlisting}}}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I've never worked with beamer `\note`. Could you please add a minimal example for your problem which compiles?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Welcome! One problem with the snippet you provide is an unmatched brace.  But even so, like `verbatim`, `lstlisting` does strange things with category codes of characters which usually precludes it from being in the argument of another macro.

Inspired by [this post to the beamer mailing list](http://osdir.com/ml/tex.latex.beamer.general/2008-07/msg00052.html), I found a workaround with the `\lstinputlisting` command.  You have to put your code snippet in a file, but using the `linerange` options you can excerpt multiple snippets from the same file.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeameroption{show notes}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
first frame
\note{\lstinputlisting[language=tex,linerange=7-10]{Untitled.tex}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much! Unfortunately I don't have the required reputation to vote your answer up. But I would definitely would…

Comment: @Normen: Glad it worked for you.  You can accept the answer anytime.  You need 15 rep for upvoting.  You get 5 for asking a question that's upvoted and 2 for accepting an answer.  So you're nearly there already. `:-)`

Answer (score 6):

Using `\lstinputlisting` as suggested by Matthew is one possibility. However, if you (like me) prefer to not have dozens of small listing files separated from the LaTeX sources, you could also render the listing into a `lrbox` box and `\usebox` this inside the `\note`:

```
\newsavebox{\LstA}

% Verbatim material in commands (\note{}) not possible --> box it
\begin{lrbox}{\LstA}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C]
int fak( int n ) {
 for( int i = n-1; i > 1; --i )
   n *= i;
 return n;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{lrbox}

\begin{frame}{Recursive Algorithm}

  \note{ Iterative solution:\par\usebox{\LstA}}
\end{frame}
```

For `minted` things are a tiny bit more complicated, which, however is covered in this question: [workaround for minted environments in in Beamer notes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450859/workaround-for-minted-environments-in-in-beamer-notes)

Answer (score 4):

I highly recommend the "[minted](http://code.google.com/p/minted/)" package for all code listings. Note that if you use this on a beamer slide, it must be fragile:

```
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Python rocks}
\begin{minted}{python}
def foo(self, bar):
   return bar
\end{minted}
\end{frame}
```

Note: The minted package needs [Pygments](http://pygments.org/) for syntax highlighting.

Comment: Oh, that sounds interesting.  I tried it OMM and I got a message that says that 'pygmentize' has to be installed.  What is that and how would one install it?

Comment: @Matt: Welcome to tex.sx! A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the 'code' button (101010).

Comment: @Matt: Does ``minted'' solve this issue? Or is it just a general recommendation. I can't switch directly, though, I already have created a bunch of specialized listing style files.

Comment: @Matt pygmentize is a program for code highlighting and typesetting. Its also used by Python documentation. minted is the wrapper for LaTeX. You will also need -shell-escape on your command line.

Comment: @Normen It should do what you want. Did you have problems?

Comment: Have you actually tried if this does work in `\note` commands? AFAIK `minted` is also a verbatim-like environment, hence cannot be passed as argument to commands (like `\note`).

Comment: @Daniel I'm having trouble using it in the note command, hoping to find some workaround!

Comment: @JoeCorneli: Render the listing in a `lrbox` and unpack it with `\usebox` inside the `\note` command.

Comment: @Daniel, it doesn't seem to work with minted.  I get an error complaining about catcodes. ```l.1 ...={\catcode`\$=3\catcode`\^=7\catcode`\_=8}]```.

Comment: @Daniel I made a MWE that gives me a different error, and put it here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450859/workaround-for-minted-environments-in-in-beamer-notes