# Beamer Latex Code Error In Listings Environment

Tags: beamer, errors, listings

I want to display a short latex code in my beamer. The code is also the about beamer. And I don't want to use the `\lstinputlisting{file.tex}`. So is there any way to do that?
Here is the code without error. Anyway, when I the three disable lines are enable, error occur.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    language=[latex]tex,
    breaklines=true}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[fragile]
        \begin{lstlisting}
            \documentclass{beamer}
            \begin{document}
%               \begin{frame}
%                   Test
%               \end{frame}
            \end{document}
        \end{lstlisting}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See this thread: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7083/27635. Probably Daniel's answer is what you are looking for.

Comment: When I try the code you suggested, it produce nothing beside the title that say "Recursive Algorithm"

Comment: I didn't mean to use that code, I mean that probably using boxes is the only alternative way to `\lstinputlisting`

Comment: @karlkoeller What did you mean? Create a box inside the frame? Create the listing inside box and inside the frame?

Comment: Do you want an answer?

Comment: Yes. I really want.

Comment: Done.... Does it work as you expected?

Comment: It works! Nice.

Comment: To answer your queston below: yes, I tested the code. Do you stii want me to write an answer showing all possible options? I ask because I see you already accepted an answer.

Comment: Actually, it works. And I want yours because it seems you don't need auxiliary environment, which is easy to remember. =P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to avoid using `\lstinputlisting` is to "box" the `lstlisting` environment and then use the command `\usebox` inside the frame.

MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{%
    language=[latex]tex,
    breaklines=true}

\newsavebox{\myLst}

\begin{document}

\begin{lrbox}{\myLst}
\begin{lstlisting}
    \documentclass{beamer}
    \begin{document}
%     \begin{frame}
%       Test
%     \end{frame}
    \end{document}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{lrbox}

\begin{frame}
\usebox{\myLst}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Result

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The `frame` environment *must not* be indented for such kind of frames. The »[beamer](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer)« manual says something about that on page 60:

> To determine the end of the frame, the following rule is used: The first occurence of a single line containing exactly `\end{⟨frame environment name⟩}` ends the frame. The ⟨environment name⟩ is normally `frame`, but it can be changed using the `environment` option. This special rule is needed since the frame contents is, after all, not interpreted when it is gathered.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language=[latex]tex,
  breaklines=true
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \begin{lstlisting}
    \documentclass{beamer}
      \begin{document}
%        \begin{frame}
%          Test
%        \end{frame}
      \end{document}
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: "The `frame` environment must not be indented for such kind of frames." Why is that please?

Comment: @ChrisH: I don't know the reason. Just read about that somewhere. But I don't remember where.

Comment: True. However, a `\end{frame}` inside the `lstlisting` environment *must* be indented.

Comment: @ChrisH please refer to page 60 of the `beamer` manual for an explanation on how material is processed when the `fragile` option is used. In fact, you (Thorsten), could add some of that explanation to your answer if you like :-)

Comment: The three disable line \begin{frame} Test \end{frame} are the code I want to display on my beamer screen. The indent is just make me easy to see and find common error only.

Comment: Everyone! There is no error if you do not enable the three lines!

Comment: @SayOL of course, there isn't; that's part of Thorsten's answer :-) All you have to do is to place the last `\end{frame}` *without* indentation and the inner `\end{frame}` *with* indentation.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I think I've found the relevant part and added it.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina It still produce error event I remove all the indentation and start every line from the beginning left margin.

Comment: @SayOL please read my comment carefully; not every line must start from the left. The inner `\end{frame}` *has* to be indented.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I am not clear about your comment. When I enable the three disable lines, the inner \end{frame} is already indented and the outside \end{frame} is not indented. This is what you meant?

Comment: @SayOL yes. The inner `\end{frame}` has to be indented; the outer one, not. Delete auxiliary files and re-compile.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, OK, it's the use of `[fragile]` that I need to look up.  I hadn't taken that from Thorsten's answer.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina did you try to compile the code? And could you please give the answer? I tries to delete aux file and even save as a new file then compile but not work. Note I am using MikTex 2.9 as my distribution and TexStudio, TexMaker, Texwork as my IDEs. And I test all of my IDE, they produce the same error, "Missing } inserted \end{frame}" and many other errors.

Comment: @SayOL: Of course I have tested the code in my example and it works fine for me. Either with or without the commented lines. It's quite difficult to say why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: @ThorstenDonig I found the mistake! Actually, I indented using **Tab** keyboard not the **Space** keyboard. Now it works :)