# workaround for minted environments in in Beamer notes

Tags: beamer, minted

A work around for adding code to beamer notes is described here:
[LaTeX beamer: Code listings in notes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7083/latex-beamer-code-listings-in-notes). Here is how I've adapted it for use with Minted:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeameroption{show notes}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{minted}{text}
Qux
\end{minted}

Goodbye.\note{hello}
\end{frame}

\newsavebox{\LstA}
\begin{lrbox}{\LstA}
\begin{minted}{text}
foo bar
\end{minted}
\end{lrbox}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
second frame
\note{Here is some code in a note:
  \usebox{\LstA}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I get the following error:

> ! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
>   Type  H   for immediate help.
>   ...
>
> l.1 `\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]`

If I keep pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, a PDF does build that seems to have the right contents - but could the errors be made to go away?

Comment: related feature request: https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/496

Comment: If your document compiles with an error, don't look at the broken output which might or might not be a valid pdf file. After an error, Tex only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to set the `minted` environment in the horizontal box created by `lrbox` you need to recustom `Verbatim` to be `BVerbatim`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeameroption{show notes}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{minted}{text}
Qux
\end{minted}

Goodbye.\note{hello}
\end{frame}

\newsavebox{\LstA}
\begin{lrbox}{\LstA}
\RecustomVerbatimEnvironment{Verbatim}{BVerbatim}{}%
\begin{minted}{text}
foo bar
\end{minted}
\end{lrbox}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
second frame
\note{Here is some code in a note:
  \usebox{\LstA}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The trick is used in line 987 of `minted.sty` for `mintinline`.

You can define a `Bminted` environment:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeameroption{show notes}
\usepackage{minted}

\newenvironment{Bminted}[2][]
 {\VerbatimEnvironment
  \RecustomVerbatimEnvironment{Verbatim}{BVerbatim}{}%
  \begin{minted}[#1]{#2}}
 {\end{minted}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\begin{minted}{text}
Qux
\end{minted}

Goodbye.\note{hello}
\end{frame}

\newsavebox{\LstA}
\begin{lrbox}{\LstA}
\begin{Bminted}[showspaces]{text}
foo bar
\end{Bminted}
\end{lrbox}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
second frame
\note{Here is some code in a note:
  \usebox{\LstA}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I added the `showspaces` option just by way of example, in order to make sure that `minted` options are honored.

Comment: I filed a feature request at https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/215